# how to use a spark dataframe column to look up an array

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a scenario such as what is included below, where I need to look up a sequence for each id value and if there is a match found, I need to get the corresponding name and populate the Name column in the dataframe (I purposely kept it this way to avoid join)..
scenario

[image]

I was able to create a generic method that does the job, but the problem with this implementation is if the Array is too large it blows up datanode heap space..

v1 : does not scale

```
def colTransform(refCol: String,newCol: String,lookUpArray: Array[Seq[Any]],index: Int)(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    df.withColumn(newCol,
       concat_ws("",array(
                lookUpArray.map{c =>
                           when(col(refCol).contains(c(0)), c(index).toString).otherwise(lit(""))
                            }: _*
                )
            )
        )
 }
```

the second version is simpler, but has a subtle issue

```
def colTransform(
refCol: String,newCol: String,lookUpArray: Array[Seq[Any]],index: Int)(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    df.withColumn(newCol,
        lit(s"${lookUpArray.filter{c =>
                    df(refCol) == lit(c(0))
                    }.map{c => if (c.length == 0) "Unknown" else c(index)}.mkString("")}")
        )
}
```

the issue is, the filter method applied on lookUpArray (line 3) expects a boolean value.. so I supply df(refCol) == lit(c(0)).. but that would always evaluate to false, as the type on the left is of Column where that on the right is String. It compiles and runs, but the end result is an empty column (because everything gets filtered out, and then mkString("") on an empty Seq results in a ""..
If you have any advice or thought, please let me know..

Comment: Why do you need `s" "` in `lit`?

Comment: @gorros : I have used string interpolation to guarantee the return type to be string

Comment: just use `col("name").cast(StringType)`